# Is there a specific SQL Server 2008 R2 Permission to run DBCC CHECKIDENT?

Tags: permissions, dbcc

MS Docs (Books online) states the caller must either own the containing schema or be a member of fixed DB roles. (sysadmin, db_owner, db_ddladmin).

Is there a specific permission or set of permissions, that could be granted to allow this in SQL Server 2008 R2?

I have a case where I need to give the permission but with the least amount of privilege and want to avoid creating a stored procedure (with execute as) that allows the specific set of tables they need to perform this against.

They also need TRUNCATE however that's covered with the ALTER permission.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that MS-Docs on [DBCC CHECKIDENT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkident-transact-sql) are really clear:

**Permissions**

> Caller must own the schema that contains the table, or be a member of the **sysadmin** fixed server role, the **db_owner** fixed database role, or the **db_ddladmin** fixed database role.